# DT table Shiny R formatStyle

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

How can I set the first row bold in function formatStyle?

Example:

```
datatable(iris, options = list(pageLength = 5)) %>%
  formatStyle(0,target="row", fontWeight = 'bold')
```

Answer (score 3):

This could be achieved via the helper function `styleRow` which allows you to target the rows which you want to style::

```r
library(DT)

datatable(iris, options = list(pageLength = 5)) %>% 
  formatStyle(0, target = "row", fontWeight = styleRow(1, "bold"))
```

[image]